# Twenty Troubles

Tags: knowledge, number-sequence

What does this list represent?

> 20 (e.g.)
> 20 (exactly)
> 20 (compared to 350)
> 20 (compared to 3)
>
> 20 (e.g.)
> 20 (when scored by the NY Giants in 1991)
> 20...21...22...23...
> 20 (when the last in this list)

Hint:

> Result of rifle placed by oaf (7)

Hint 2:

> Dude found in part of Guam?  Why? (3)

Hint 3:

> MST3K movie has Chet troubled in mill (8)

Comment: Sorry are those numbers hinting at wordlength or its position on the list?

Comment: The hints are cryptic clues ended by the number of letters in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Lot** of credit to **@Stiv** for this who got the final answer when I was turning down a large rabbit hole (see edits for a laugh).

Logic at the bottom for the starting point, though I think it was almost impossible before the hints.

These are all relating to:

> The song lyrics for [Heartaches By The Number](https://www.google.ie/search?hl&q=heartaches%20by%20the%20number%20lyrics), specifically the last word in each line (assuming you're not looking at a version that combines pairs of lines)

20 (e.g.)

> Number

20 (exactly)

> Score

20 (compared to 350)

> Less

20 (compared to 3)

> More

20 (e.g.)

> Number

20 (when scored by the NY Giants in 1991)

> Win (this really threw me - knowing nothing about American Football, [googling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1991_New_York_Giants_season) it showed me the Giants had a mediocre 1991 season after winning the previous Super Bowl. Didn't realise it had been in January

20...21...22...23...

> Counting

20 (when the last in this list)

> End

**Logic for identifying the connection:**

Hint #2

> Dude found in part of GUam? WhY? (3)  => GUY

Hint #3

> MST3K movie has Chet troubled in mill (8) => MITCHELL (only possible anagram of chet inside mill, plus on a list of MST3K movies)

So that gives us

> Guy Mitchell, for which the only reference I can see is [this singer]. Can't see how any of his songs listed are relevant to the clues though[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guy_Mitchell).

However, having now solved Hint #1

> Result of rifle placed by oaf (7) => FALLOUT (FAL + LOUT)

It turns out that:

> Heartaches By the Number was a Guy Mitchell song featured in Fallout: New Vegas. So presumably all the clues refer either to the game, or to heartaches, or troubles

Puzzle title:

> The second half of the first line of [Heartaches By the Number](https://genius.com/Guy-mitchell-heartaches-by-the-number-lyrics) is "...troubles by the score". 20 = a score, title is literally "troubles" by(beside) a score

Comment: You might be on to something here - that song has the lyric rot13("Gebhoyrf ol gur fpber") and many others like it - since that has a numeric connotation to '20' that's a very strong connection...

Comment: Ha! Had just added that, snap!

Comment: I've got it! But you made the breakthrough so I think you should post it: each line is rot13(n pyhr gb gur ynfg jbeq va gur svefg 8 yvarf bs gur fbat: ahzore, fpber, yrff, zber, ahzore, jva, pbhagvat, raq)

Comment: Also, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Bowl_XXV) is the relevant match for the 1991 reference.

Comment: Hey, thanks a million. Added the answers in, I was heading the wring way. That one you linked had really thrown me - googling it put me a year out

Comment: No worries :) Nice to see an 'old' puzzle being solved after a few months!